# How to edit caption for images and exclude it from excerption query?

Tags: images, captions

I have 2 questions for caption for images:
- how to edti them with bold, italics and so on? I do it, but it doesn't work.
- if the image is first, how to exclude caption from excerpt in query especially for frontpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question- HTML support for captions was a new feature in wordpress 3.4, if you have any version prior to that, it won't work

I'm not sure if i understood your 2nd question, but to exclude the caption from not displaying on the page, you'll have to either delete the caption from the image or edit your theme's template files

### UPDATE

First if the image was inserted in the page content, it is inserted in the form of a shortcode, so you can use the filter `img_caption_shortcode` to override the default shortcode output.

If it's set as featured image, instead of using `the_post_thumbnail`, use `get_post_thumbnail_id` & generate the `img` tag yourself & skip the caption.

Next to permanently disable the captions functionality(you already cleared you don't want to do that), you can use this `add_filter( 'disable_captions', '__return_true' );`

If you want a WYSIWYG editor in captions, there isn't any hook for that. You'll have to code it yourself

Comment: I mean i have post with the image and some text, then i show it on front page. Unfortunately it shows text from caption as first. I  need caption so i can't just delete it. Is there any code to make query and show posts on frontpage without caption?

Comment: edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example below where you can embed html tags within the Caption box and it will style your caption text accordingly. 
[image]

Also, don't forget that WordPress applies a default class of `wp-caption` to your caption elements for which you can further use to specify custom CSS properties, so technically you can wrap text within your caption box also using `<span class="special-class">` tags with special classes and give them unique styling.

Comment: Thanks, but how to edit caption without html? I've got to enable it to some people not too good in coding. Any plugin or code to edit captions in regular admin panel/ writing posts?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I added: 
    "if ( is_home() )
    add_filter('img_caption_shortcode', create_function('$a, $b, $c',
    'return $c;'), 10, 3);"